# Why Mathematica giving me wrong result for such basic calculation

Tags: numerics

Why I am getting the wrong result using **Do Loop**. It is a very simple calculation the answer should be 1.1111...

```
a = 1.11111111111111111;
Do[a = 2 a - a, {35}];
a
```

[image: No Significant digits are available to display.]

It shows **No Significant digits are available to display**
Moreover, using For Loop

[image: It is still not showing me the original value 1.11...]

It is still not showing me the original value 1.111111...

I do not why it giving me **True** for a-2==a-3, which is a bit awkward.

Comment: I would suspect that this is dependent on how machine precision numbers are being represented on the hardware _Mathematica Online_ is running on. On my local machine running _Mathematica_, the error does not propagate catastrophically, but I'm actually a little surprised to see that.

Comment: Mathematica is my favorite. As I was just watching a few videos on youtube then this came:
A guest lecture was given by Prof. Richard Fateman to Stanford CS50 about Mathematica
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vm9IxKsgpVM
Few problems shown by the Professor, still persist even in the newer version of Mathematica in some way or another.

Comment: Yes taking a=10/9 giving me correct result. File can be found here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pushpendra050/Published/WrongResultsMathematica.nb
But why does Mathematica give the wrong numeric result when taking some other values. It got high level Accuracy and Precision though.

Comment: The reason that I deleted my comment is that I wasn't and still am not sure about the `a-2 == a -3` part. There are two questions in this question and perhaps more.  I will wait to read the answers submitted by experienced users.

Comment: Evaluate `Precision[a = 1.11111111111111111]` then `Do[Print[Row[{a = 2 a - a, Spacer[5], Precision[a]}]], {35}];` to see the precision degrade.

Comment: Say we have 4 binary digits of precision,    Now as an example assume: a=1111e0 where e is the exponent. 2a= 1110e1 and 2a-a= 1110e1-1111e0= 1110e1-0111e1= 0111e1= 1110e0 where we lost 1 digit of precision.

Comment: The issue is, as @Bob alludes, to the automatic precision tracking in arbitrary precision numbers. By entering in more than 17 digits, you don't have a machine-precision number. Consider `Print@Precision[a = 1.1111111111111111];
Do[Print[Row[{a = 2 a - a, Spacer[5], Precision[a]}]], {35}];` and `Print@Precision[a = 1.11111111111111111];
Block[{$MinPrecision = Precision[a], $MaxPrecision = Precision[a]},
  Do[Print[Row[{a = 2 a - a, Spacer[5], Precision[a]}]], {35}]];`

Comment: Note that the model used in arbitrary-precision treats errors as uncorrelated, so the max. uncertainty in `2 a - a` is three times the uncertainty in `a`. This can be seen in @Bob's code by the precision decreasing by `Log10[3.]` at each iteration.

Comment: Thank you all @BobHanlon @Daniel and @Micheal for giving me some insight of this issue. I have incorporated the changes here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/pushpendra050/Published/MathematicaNumericalPrecision.nb 
Moreover, if we add **`** at the end of numeric value then its precision got increased and this issue is resolved for the higher number of iteration as pointed out by @Bill Watts.

Comment: This is a well known example and is used to illustrate that some computations should be done in fixed precision. Which can be done like so: ``In[509]:= a = 1.11111111111111111;
NumericalMath`FixedPrecisionEvaluate[Do[a = 2 a - a, {35}], 17];
a

Out[511]= 1.1111111111111111``  (Voting to close since it is fairly well known, and more to do with math than Mathematica, other than the fact that the software uses arbitrary precision arithmetic by default.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just increase the precision of your input.

```
a = 1.11111111111111111`50
Do[a = 2 a - a, {35}]
a

1.1111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000
1.111111111111111110000000000000000

a = 1.11111111111111111`50
For[i = 0, i <= 35, i++, a = 2 a - a]
a

1.1111111111111111100000000000000000000000000000000
1.11111111111111111000000000000000

a - 2 == a - 3
False
```

Comment: Yes, it solves the issue. but I recommend not to define the precision by a value (as 50) in the above case. **a = 1.1111111111`** would solve the problem for a higher number of iteration. If we add value at the end then increasing the number of iteration would again give wrong results.

Comment: @Pushpendra - use `a = 1.11111111111111111 // RootApproximant` or `a = 1.11111111111111111 // Rationalize[#, 0] &`

Comment: I agree with @BobHanlon.  If precision is giving you trouble, inputting exact numbers generally solves the problem.  Just be aware that calculations will be slower than using machine or extended precision numbers.